# Installing Istio with Helm on Minikube fails

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Running the following commands as in the docs on my clean Ubuntu 16.04 server:

```
minikube start --memory=7168 --cpus=3 --kubernetes-version=v1.10.0 --vm-driver=kvm2
kubectl apply -f istio-1.0.4/install/kubernetes/helm/helm-service-account.yaml
helm init --service-account tiller --wait
helm install istio-1.0.4/install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system
```

However, instead of a successful installation I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: release istio failed: customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "envoyfilters.networking.istio.io" already exists
```

Versions:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.0", GitCommit:"ddf47ac13c1a9483ea035a79cd7c10005ff21a6d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-03T21:04:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

istioctl version
Version: 1.0.4
GitRevision: d5cb99f479ad9da88eebb8bb3637b17c323bc50b
User: root@8c2feba0b568
Hub: docker.io/istio
GolangVersion: go1.10.4
BuildStatus: Clean
```

I already tried to `minikube delete`, as well as adding `rm -rf ~/.minikube` just to be on the safe side but still I'm getting a resource exist error. Any ideas?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing with GKE today, find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you're not going to like this. It seems to be an issue with helm v2.12.0.

You'll need to downgrade to v2.11.0 for it to work successfully. I've included some of the necessary changes to your helm install to make it work below.

```
# download the right client version
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/helm/master/scripts/get | DESIRED_VERSION=v2.11.0 bash

# init the right tiller server
helm init \
--tiller-image gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.11.0 \
--service-account tiller
```